# Facebook crawler/scrape specific port

Tags: html, web-crawler, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-debugger, addtoany

I have two websites hosted on a single domain on two ports.

```
1- News site on www.mysite.com
2- Jokes site on www.mysite.com:8082
```

when I share/debug an url of site-1 then the meta tags are used from site-1 index page and which is needed and works fine as intended.

BUT

when I share/debug an url of site-2 then also the meta tags are used for crawling is of site-1 i.e. all the tags in site-2 are ignored.

is there any way to tell the crawlers to use sites with port specified.

Note: I am using addToAny plugin of the sharing, any help from there is also commendable.